# querying nested object arrays from mongodb / nodejs

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb, nested

I am trying to figure out how to query the nested objects inside the `Components` object. The data was inserted from a parsed json file.

**Query**

```
var query = {}
cursor = db.collection("workflows").find(query).toArray(function(err, result) {
if (err) throw err;

console.log(result);
db.close();
    });
```

This data is returned when I run the query above:

> At this point i'm just trying to get it to filter in some manner. I've tried `Name:'Test WF'` and other variations of that but still can't get a filtered response.

```
[ { _id: 5c77040838f9d322b89bbd82,
texto:
 { _id: 12,
   LocalCachePath: 'Z:\\Test\\Cache',
   SharedCachePath: [],
   Name: 'Test WF',
   Desc: 'I\'m testing',
   Components: [Array] } },
{ _id: 5c7704164413692978a9dd1a,
texto:
 { _id: 'Workflow-2019.02.22-23.21.15-MKRU',
   LocalCachePath: 'Z:\\MAITest\\Cache',
   SharedCachePath: [],
   Name: 'Test WF',
   Desc: 'I\'m testing',
   Components: [Array] } },
 { _id: 5c77046335b012379c99951b,
texto:
 { _id: '154',
   LocalCachePath: 'Z:\\Test\\Cache',
   SharedCachePath: [],
   Name: 'Test WF',
   Desc: 'I\'m testing',
   Components: [Array] } },
 { _id: 5c7704787bde6f36543d1016,
texto:
 { _id: 'Workflow-2019.02.22-23.21.15-MKRU',
   LocalCachePath: 'Z:\\Test\\Cache',
   SharedCachePath: [],
   Name: 'Test WF',
   Desc: 'I\'m testing',
   Components: [Array] } } ]
```

Any insight would be helpful i'm stumbling through this one step at a time.

Here's another query that is giving me results but i guess my issue is going to be to parse out my results as variables.

```
var query = {'texto.Components.0.Name' : {$gt: ''}}
// var query = {'testo.Name' : {$gt: ''} }
 cursor = db.collection("workflows").find(query).toArray(function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
```

Comment: Nice `Desc`! What do you mean by "filter in some manner"? Can you be more specific?

Comment: What exactly do you want to have returned?

Comment: I really want to get to the Components level and access the data in their sub nodes. I would like to be able to pull the field name and value for each node in the file.

Answer (score 4):

Use dot notation (e.g. texto.Name) to query and retrieve fields from nested objects, example:

```
var query = {'texto.Name': 'Test WF'}
```

Comment: Cool. It worked right away. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Simply

```
db.getCollection('TestQueries').find({'texto.Name': 'Test WF'})
```

Regex used for Case Insensitive.

```
db.getCollection('TestQueries').find({"texto.Name":{
                                 '$regex' : '^test wa$', '$options' : 'i'
                                 }})
```

Using collation

```
db.fruit.createIndex( {"texto.Name": 1},{ collation: {
                     locale: 'en', strength: 2 
                     } } )

db.getCollection('TestQueries').find( 
            { "texto.Name": "test wa" } ).collation( { locale: 'en', strength: 2 } 
            )
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, this is what i have but i'm getting db.getCollection is not a function   var query = {'texto.Name': 'Test WF'}
 cursor =  db.getCollection('workflows').find({query})(function(err, result) {
  if (err) throw err;
    
    console.log(result);
    db.close();
 });

Comment: I just run this on Robo 3T. Thats why  i am used getCollection.
I think u can try with db.collection db.collection()

Comment: i have a same data flow but it is giving all data instead of matched data below is my code.                               {
    "$match": {
      "$or": [
        {
          "product_categories.product_list.name": {
            "$regex": ".*samo.*",
            "$options": "i"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `$elemMatch`. It is longer, but allows for multiple fields query.

```
db.getCollection('TestQueries').find({texto: {$elemMatch: {Name: "test wa"} }))
```

Official docs [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/#a-single-nested-document-meets-multiple-query-conditions-on-nested-fields)